# How can I combine two on click functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-performance

I have two on click function... somewhat like below. It is working. However, I have a feeling that the on click functions can be combined into one for optimization reasons. Basically when xx is clicked it shows some elements, hides some elements, and adds a class. When yy is clicked it does exactly the opposite. Can these be combined?

```
/*clicking the search icon on the top*/ 
$(".xx").on("click",function(){
        $a.show();
        $b.hide();
        $c.addClass("myClass");

}); 

/*clicking the cross icon on the top*/
$(".yy").on("click",function(){
        $c.removeClass("myClass");
        $a.hide();
        $b.show();                  
});
```

Comment: a demo or markup will make it better.

Comment: I do not see any reason.  What are you going to optimize? Script size?

Comment: Yeep. Just asking if it is possible...?

Comment: You can do `$(".xx, .yy").click(...)` to combine them. But then it will have to contain something like `if ($(this).hasClass('xx'))` to do the xx-specific stuff.

Comment: They're different methods for different elements. But with your HTML code will be easier to undestand.

Comment: If this is an on/off toggle, why not just use a check box and use the `object.checked` property to determine what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `toggle` function, described [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) and the `toggleClass` function described [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

This could look something like:

```
function handleClick()
{
    $a.toggle();
    $b.toggle();
    $c.toggleClass("myClass");
}

$(".xx").on("click", handleClick);
$(".yy").on("click", handleClick);
```

Comment: How is this equivalent?  `xx` is supposed to add the class, `yy` is supposed to remove the class. Yours toggles the class no matter which he clicks on.

Comment: Thanks it helped.. I combined the two on click further $(".xx,.yy")...Thanks.. I have been able to adapt this solution

Comment: @Barmar -- right you are, somehow I misread what the OP wanted.  Dilbert -- glad you were able to find use in it then...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can combine them with a single function. As you are hiding, showing and adding class to some elements you have to check for corresponding element which is clicked. Here's the code:

```
$(".xx, .yy").on("click", function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("xx")){
       $a.show();
       $b.hide();
       $c.addClass("myClass");
    }else if($(this).hasClass("yy")){
       $c.removeClass("myClass");
       $a.hide();
       $b.show();
    }
});
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use attr for checking the class name also can hasClass()

```
$(".xx, .yy").on("click",function(){
    var c_name = $(this).attr('class');
    if(c_name == 'xx'){
        $a.show();
        $b.hide();
        $c.addClass("myClass");
    }else if(c_name == 'yy'){
        $c.removeClass("myClass");
        $a.hide();
        $b.show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding class to $c, add the class to a common parent, and use CSS to control visibility of $a and $b

```
 .a, .b {display:none;}
 .parentClass .a, .parentClass .b{
    display:block
 }
```

and add or removeClass depending on which element is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You could use toggle functions and pass a boolean value into them:

```
$(".xx, .yy").on("click",function(){
    var custBoolean = $(this).is(".xx");
    $a.toggle(custBoolean);
    $b.toggle(!custBoolean);
    $c.toggleClass("myClass", custBoolean);
});
```